# Deleting relational data in MongoDB - Removing specific element from Array

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, relationship

I have a collection of users and a collection of articles. A user holds multiple articles in an array. Now I'm trying to delete an article from a User's array of articles in MongoDB. So far I have

```
exports.delete = function(req, res, next) {
  const articleId = req.params.id;

  Article.findOneAndRemove({_id: articleId})
    .then((deletedArticle)=> {
      const authorId = deletedArticle.author;
      console.log("AUTHOR:"+authorId);

      User.update( { _id: authorId }, { $pull: { articles: [ _id: deletedArticle.id ] } }  )


      res.status(204).send(deletedArticle)
    })
    .catch(next);
}
```

this *does* delete this article itself, however, not the reference to the article saved in the array the User object holds. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the square brackets in your query to curly:

```
User.update( { _id: authorId }, { $pull: { articles: { _id: deletedArticle.id } } } )
```

This would obviously require that the _id in the articles array is the same as the article collection, which depends on how you populate the array (I have a feeling you are doing that part right, but just wanted to mention that possibility up front).